# Weighted average element-wise between two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of number and I want to compute a weighted average element-wise between these array and store it in a new array.

The solution I use for now is :

```
array_1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
array_2 = [2,3,4,5,6]

weight_1 = 0.5
weight_2 = 0.5

array_3 = np.zeros(array_1.shape)

for i in range(0, len(array_1)) : 
    array_3[i] = np.average(a=[array_1[i], array_2[i]], weights=[weight_1, weight_2])

print(array_3)
>> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

The problem is that it is not really efficient. How can I do that more efficiently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use NumPy's vectorised operations. To do so, first convert your lists to arrays and then just multiply each array with the respective weight and take the sum

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
array_2 = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])

weight_1 = 0.5
weight_2 = 0.5

array_3 = weight_1*array_1 + weight_2*array_2
# array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
```

A direct NumPy solution using `np.average` would be the following, where `axis=0` means take the average row wise (using both columns). `np.vstack()` simply stacks the two arrays vertically.

```
np.average(np.vstack((array_1, array_2)), axis=0, weights=[weight_1, weight_2])
```

As pointed out by @yatu, you can also pass a list of your arrays and specify the axis

```
np.average([array_1, array_2], axis=0, weights=[weight_1, weight_2])
```

**Timing comparison inspired by the comments on @yatu's answer**: As you can see, list comprehension and zip is slightly faster here but then this performance is for small arrays. I am sure, for large arrays, the vectorised solution will take over

**Devesh's method**

```
%timeit result = [ item1 * weight_1 + item2 * weight_2 for item1, item2 in zip(array_1, array_2)]
# 25.5 µs ± 3.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

```
%timeit np.average([array_1, array_2], axis=0, weights=[weight_1, weight_2])
# 42.9 µs ± 2.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

```
%timeit np.average(np.vstack((array_1, array_2)), axis=0, weights=[weight_1, weight_2])
# 44.8 µs ± 4.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) both iterators, and multiply each element with the corresponding weight

```
array_1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
array_2 = [2,3,4,5,6]

weight_1 = 0.5
weight_2 = 0.5

#Zip both iterators and multiply weight with corresponding item
result = [ item1 * weight_1 + item2 * weight_2 for item1, item2 in zip(array_1, array_2)]
print(result)
```

The output will be

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're using **NumPy**, you can easily vectorize this by doing:

```
array_1 = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
array_2 = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])

weight_1 = 0.5
weight_2 = 0.5

array_1*weight_1 + array_2*weight_2
# array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
```

---

**Can this be generalised for multiple arrays and weights?**

For a more generalizable answer, the best way is to use  [`np.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html), which accepts an `array_like` both for the arrays and the `weights` to be applied to each of these:

```
np.average([array_1, array_2], weights=[weight_1, weight_2], axis=0)
# array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
```

Comment: No one for a `zip` solution :)

Comment: Well OP did say a more efficient solution. So we're looking for a vectorized one here @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: So numpy vectorization is more efficient then zipping and list comp @yatu ?

Comment: Yes it generally is, as you're dropping all looping to `c` level @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: Check my answer for timing performance. Your method indeed wins here **but** I am sure that for large arrays, vectorised solution will take over

Comment: Indeed. If OP wants performance, it is presumable that we're talking about large arrays. And the way to check performance here, and always with numpy, is with much larger samples

Comment: @yatu: I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the equation for the weighted average be:

`(array_1*weight_1 + array_2*weight_2)/(weight_1 + weighted_2)`

[image]

Comment: This does not seem like an answer but may be a relevant comment. Please post as comment to the question. Optionally link to the theory image.

Comment: I wanted to, but I couldn't post it as a comment since my reputation is lower than 50 and I could only post it as an answer