# Weighted element-wise between two arrays, numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to perform

```
array_0 = np.array([ [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3] ])
array_1 = np.array([ [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3] ])
weights = np.array([ 1, 5 ])

result = array_0 * weights[0] + array_1 * weights[1]
```

Is there a `numpy` function that does just that?

Obviously, I could use `numpy.average()` with `1==sum(weights)`, and then multiply the result to compensate, but my question is: **is there a function that does the sum-product without tricks?**

Also, my question may be invalid: I assume that `w1*A1+w2*A2+w3*A3+...` results in as many for loops as there are operation, not just a single elementwise for loop.

There is a similar question, which does not work in my case:

[element-wise weighted average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327842/weighted-average-element-wise-between-two-arrays)

Comment: It should be equivalent to `np.array([array_0, array_1]).transpose(1,2,0) @ weights`, resorting to a single matmul. I'm not sure it's any faster though.

Comment: That loop in multiplication is a C-loop, so you shouldn't have any noticeable loop overhead by just multiplying and adding directly.

Comment: @SUTerliakov I have tried Your solution, it is slower, indeed. But... I don't get it. s=a+b+c+d+e+f is faster than np.sum([a,b,c,d,e,f]). I assumed that the explicit addition is at least 5 times looping through all the elements. np.sum() however, loops once (plus array creation time). At the very least, I though np.sum() would be on par with explicit addition, but with 8 arrays, each 800x800, the explicit addition is about 2x faster.